# getting routes right with asp.net webapi 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my routes to work but end up getting an error.

This is currently my only route:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "ActionApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

I commented this one out as I thought it was the problem

```
   //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //    name: "DefaultApi",
    //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    //);
```

These are the two methods I have :

```
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
      Product[] products = new Product[] 
      { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
      };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    [ActionName("GetAllProducts")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProductsAction()
    {
        return products;
    }
  }
```

When trying to access it on this URL: `http://localhost:27720/api/products/GetAllProducts` I get an error: `Multiple actions were found that match the request`

How can that be? I have named one of them with a specific action method. Is this by design or did I configure my routes wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()` and `public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProductsAction()` with the `ActionName("GetAllProducts")` attribute definitely resolve to the same URL, hence the *Multiple actions were found that match the request* error.

Change the action name of the one or the method name of the other...or remove one of the methods because they are currently redundant.